# Edit PDF in NSData Format ? iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, pdf, nsdata

I have an pdf which has been saved as an NSData object. Is it possible to somehow edit the contents of this NSData object (e.g change certain field names) and then reconvert to a PDF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSData object IS the PDF file. You just have to find an iOS library capable of loading a PDF file from a NSData object, modifying it and saving it again to a NSData object.